# Extract Env Variable from an Appfog PHP app

Tags: php, environment-variables, appfog

In the past I have successfully setup phpmyadmin in Appfog. I added username and password credentials to phpmyadmin's Env Variables using the Appfog console. Phpmyadmin picks up those Env Variables and uses them to help the with the login process.

Now I want to put a SMTP password into an Env Variable and access it with a PHP library so that I don't have to store the SMTP password in a static PHP file on the server.

I added an Env Variable to the PHP instance that is hosting my SlimPHP installation on Appfog.

How do I extract that Env Variable from the PHP server correctly?  I have echoed out a phpinfo() and can see the Env Variable in the output.  I have used getinv, but I keep coming up with a 'index not found' error using the following code:

```
$p = getenv['PMA_SMTP_P'];
```

**var_dump($_ENV) Result:**

```
array(0) {}
```

**phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT) Result:**

```
PMA_SMTP_P variable is displayed with the correct value.
```

**phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES) Result:**

```
PMA_SMTP_P variable not shown in the result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

But, the short answer, is you should be able to do:

```
$_ENV["PMA_SMTP_P"]
```

Or

```
getenv['PMA_SMTP_P'];
```

If neither is returned, we'll need more information, maybe some output from your phginfo

Comment: O, I have read the manual Dave.  I think the main problem here is that the PHP instance is hosted on an AWS.  I am hoping someone with Appfog experience has the solution I am looking for.  I tried your solution and got the following error: "Undefined index: PMA_SMTP_P" both times.

Comment: Can you var_dump($_ENV) and see what you get?  And does it show up when you do phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT) or when you do phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES) ?

Comment: Updated the OP with the results from the dumps.  Only phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT); shows the PMA_SMTP_P variable in the result.

Comment: Dave, thanks for taking me down to the base tests.  It was a silly spelling mistake.  PMA_SMPT_P instead of PMA_SMTP_P.  Checking this as the answer even though the cause was bad human typing skills.